# Unable to set the activation state to true for the application: weblogic.application.ModuleException:

Tags: maven, weblogic

```
C:\snapshotviews\app_ant2maven_view1\app_vob\app\app\app-ear>mvn antrun:run
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building WebLogic app ear 1.0.4-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-antrun-plugin:1.7:run (default-cli) @ app-ear ---
[INFO] Executing tasks

deploy-weblogic:
     [java]
     [java] Initializing WebLogic Scripting Tool (WLST) ...
     [java]
     [java] Welcome to WebLogic Server Administration Scripting Shell
     [java]
     [java] Type help() for help on available commands
     [java]
     [java]
     [java]
     [java] Build number : 1.0.4-SNAPSHOT.-SNAPSHOT
     [java] Build label  : app_1.0.4-SNAPSHOT
     [java]
     [java]
     [java]
     [java]
     [java] Admin Port : 7001
     [java] Domain Directory  : currentDomainDirectory
     [java] Domain Name  : app7001
     [java]
     [java]
     [java] Starting weblogic server ...
     [java] WLST-WLS-1462290651259: <May 3, 2016 10:50:51 AM CDT> <Info> <Security> <BEA-090905> <Disabling CryptoJ JCE Provider self-integrity check for better startup performance. To enable t
his check, specify -Dweblogic.security.allowCryptoJDefaultJCEVerification=true>
     [java] WLST-WLS-1462290651259: <May 3, 2016 10:50:51 AM CDT> <Info> <Security> <BEA-090906> <Changing the default Random Number Generator in RSA CryptoJ from ECDRBG to FIPS186PRNG. To disa
ble this change, specify -Dweblogic.security.allowCryptoJDefaultPRNG=true>
     [java] WLST-WLS-1462290651259: <May 3, 2016 10:50:51 AM CDT> <Info> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000377> <Starting WebLogic Server with Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM Version 24.51-b03 from Or
acle Corporation>
     [java] WLST-WLS-1462290651259: <May 3, 2016 10:50:52 AM CDT> <Info> <Management> <BEA-140013> <C:\snapshotviews\e872st_DeviA_app_ant2maven_view1\app_vob\app\app\app-ear\target\de
ploy\app7001\config\config.xml not found>
     [java] WLST-WLS-1462290651259: <May 3, 2016 10:50:52 AM CDT> <Info> <Management> <BEA-141254> <Generating new domain directory in C:\snapshotviews\e872st_DeviA_app_ant2maven_view1\app_
vob\app\app\app-ear\target\deploy\app7001>
     [java] WLST-WLS-1462290651259: <May 3, 2016 10:50:55 AM CDT> <Info> <Management> <BEA-141255> <Domain generation completed in 2,886 milliseconds.>
     [java] WLST-WLS-1462290651259: <May 3, 2016 10:50:55 AM CDT> <Info> <Management> <BEA-141107> <Version: WebLogic Server 10.3.4.0  Fri Dec 17 20:47:33 PST 2010 1384255 >
     [java] WLST-WLS-1462290651259: <May 3, 2016 10:50:55 AM CDT> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to STARTING>
     [java] WLST-WLS-1462290651259: <May 3, 2016 10:50:55 AM CDT> <Info> <WorkManager> <BEA-002900> <Initializing self-tuning thread pool>
     [java] WLST-WLS-1462290651259: <May 3, 2016 10:50:55 AM CDT> <Notice> <Log Management> <BEA-170019> <The server log file C:\snapshotviews\e872st_DeviA_app_ant2maven_view1\app_vob\app
\app\app-ear\target\deploy\app7001\servers\admin7001\logs\admin7001.log is opened. All server side log events will be written to this file.>
     [java] WLST-WLS-1462290651259: <May 3, 2016 10:50:55 AM CDT> <Error> <Socket> <BEA-000438> <Unable to load performance pack. Using Java I/O instead. Please ensure that wlntio.dll is in: 'C
:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\jre\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\RationalSDLC\common;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin;C:\Program F
iles (x86)\IBM\RationalSDLC\common;C:\oracle\product\client\11gR4\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Business Objects\Common\3.5\bin\NOTES\;C:\Program Files (x86)\CURL;C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\;C:\WINDOWS;C
:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Program Files (x86)\AdminStudio\10.0\Common;C:\CYGWIN\BIN;C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\Ratio
nalSDLC\ClearCase\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\gsk8\lib;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\gsk8\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\RationalSDLC\ClearCase\RemoteClient\cteapis;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\R
ationalSDLC\common;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\;C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\WindowsP
owerShell\v1.0;C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\gsk8\lib;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\gsk8\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\RationalSDLC\ClearCase\bin;C:\Program Files (x
86)\IBM\RationalSDLC\ClearCase\RemoteClient\cteapis;C:\snapshotviews\maven\apache-maven-3.3.9\bin;c:\windows\system32\wbem;;.'
     [java] WLST-WLS-1462290651259: >
     [java] WLST-WLS-1462290651259: <May 3, 2016 10:50:56 AM CDT> <Notice> <Security> <BEA-090082> <Security initializing using security realm myrealm.>
     [java] .WLST-WLS-1462290651259: <May 3, 2016 10:50:57 AM CDT> <Warning> <Store> <BEA-280101> <The persistent file store "_WLS_admin7001" is forced to use buffered I/O and so may have signi
ficantly degraded performance. Either the OS/hardware environment does not support the chosen write policy or the native wlfileio library is missing. See store open log messages for the request
ed and final write policies. See the documentation on store synchronous write policy configuration for advice.>
     [java] WLST-WLS-1462290651259: <May 3, 2016 10:50:58 AM CDT> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to STANDBY>
     [java] WLST-WLS-1462290651259: <May 3, 2016 10:50:58 AM CDT> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to STARTING>
     [java] WLST-WLS-1462290651259: <May 3, 2016 10:50:58 AM CDT> <Notice> <Log Management> <BEA-170027> <The Server has established connection with the Domain level Diagnostic Service successf
ully.>
     [java] WLST-WLS-1462290651259: <May 3, 2016 10:50:58 AM CDT> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to ADMIN>
     [java] WLST-WLS-1462290651259: <May 3, 2016 10:50:58 AM CDT> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to RESUMING>
     [java] WLST-WLS-1462290651259: <May 3, 2016 10:50:58 AM CDT> <Notice> <Server> <BEA-002613> <Channel "Default" is now listening on 127.0.0.1:7001 for protocols iiop, t3, ldap, snmp, http.>

     [java] WLST-WLS-1462290651259: <May 3, 2016 10:50:58 AM CDT> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000331> <Started WebLogic Admin Server "admin7001" for domain "app7001" running in Development
 Mode>
     [java] WLST-WLS-1462290651259: <May 3, 2016 10:50:58 AM CDT> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to RUNNING>
     [java] WLST-WLS-1462290651259: <May 3, 2016 10:50:58 AM CDT> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000360> <Server started in RUNNING mode>
     [java] Server started successfully.
     [java] Connecting to t3://127.0.0.1:7001 with userid wlsboot ...
     [java] Successfully connected to Admin Server 'admin7001' that belongs to domain 'app7001'.
     [java]
     [java] Warning: An insecure protocol was used to connect to the
     [java] server. To ensure on-the-wire security, the SSL port or
     [java] Admin port should be used instead.
     [java]
     [java] Location changed to edit tree. This is a writable tree with
     [java] DomainMBean as the root. To make changes you will need to start
     [java] an edit session via startEdit().
     [java]
     [java] For more help, use help(edit)
     [java]
     [java] Starting an edit session ...
     [java] Started edit session, please be sure to save and activate your
     [java] changes once you are done.
     [java] --- Creating Password Validator attributes
     [java] Saving all your changes ...
     [java] Saved all your changes successfully.
     [java] Activating all your changes, this may take a while ...
     [java] The edit lock associated with this edit session is released
     [java] once the activation is completed.
     [java] Activation completed
     [java]
     [java]
     [java] Starting an edit session ...
     [java] Started edit session, please be sure to save and activate your
     [java] changes once you are done.
     [java]   Creating Serveradmin7001
     [java]   Creating JDBC Connection PoolErmaDataSource
     [java]   target admin7001
     [java]   Creating JDBC Connection PoolIceDataSource
     [java]   target admin7001
     [java]   Creating JDBC Connection PoolLegacyDataSource
     [java]   target admin7001
     [java] Saving all your changes ...
     [java] Saved all your changes successfully.
     [java] Activating all your changes, this may take a while ...
     [java] The edit lock associated with this edit session is released
     [java] once the activation is completed.
     [java] WLST-WLS-1462290651259: <May 3, 2016 10:51:17 AM CDT> <Warning> <Management> <BEA-141239> <The non-dynamic attribute InternalAppsDeployOnDemandEnabled on weblogic.management.configu
ration.DomainMBeanImpl@30e793cd([app7001]) has been changed. This may require redeploying or rebooting configured entities>
     [java] WLST-WLS-1462290651259: <May 3, 2016 10:51:17 AM CDT> <Warning> <Management> <BEA-141238> <A non-dynamic change has been made which affects the server admin7001. This server must be
 rebooted in order to consume this change.>
     [java] WLST-WLS-1462290651259: <May 3, 2016 10:51:17 AM CDT> <Warning> <Management> <BEA-141239> <The non-dynamic attribute FileName on weblogic.management.configuration.LogMBeanImpl@efb4c
328([app7001]/Log[app7001]) has been changed. This may require redeploying or rebooting configured entities>
     [java] WLST-WLS-1462290651259: <May 3, 2016 10:51:17 AM CDT> <Warning> <Management> <BEA-141238> <A non-dynamic change has been made which affects the server admin7001. This server must be
 rebooted in order to consume this change.>
     [java] WLST-WLS-1462290651259: <May 3, 2016 10:51:17 AM CDT> <Warning> <Management> <BEA-141239> <The non-dynamic attribute AnonymousAdminLookupEnabled on weblogic.management.configuration
.SecurityConfigurationMBeanImpl@efb4c332([app7001]/SecurityConfiguration[app7001]) has been changed. This may require redeploying or rebooting configured entities>
     [java] WLST-WLS-1462290651259: <May 3, 2016 10:51:17 AM CDT> <Warning> <Management> <BEA-141238> <A non-dynamic change has been made which affects the server admin7001. This server must be
 rebooted in order to consume this change.>
     [java] WLST-WLS-1462290651259: <May 3, 2016 10:51:17 AM CDT> <Warning> <Management> <BEA-141239> <The non-dynamic attribute ControlFlag on weblogic.security.providers.authentication.Defaul
tAuthenticatorMBeanImpl@c5b97457([app7001]/SecurityConfiguration[app7001]/Realms[myrealm]/AuthenticationProviders[DefaultAuthenticator]) has been changed. This may require redeploying or re
booting configured entities>
     [java] WLST-WLS-1462290651259: <May 3, 2016 10:51:17 AM CDT> <Warning> <Management> <BEA-141238> <A non-dynamic change has been made which affects the server admin7001. This server must be
 rebooted in order to consume this change.>
     [java] WLST-WLS-1462290651259: <May 3, 2016 10:51:17 AM CDT> <Warning> <Management> <BEA-141239> <The non-dynamic attribute InterfaceAddress on weblogic.management.configuration.ServerMBea
nImpl@2193d17b([app7001]/Servers[admin7001]) has been changed. This may require redeploying or rebooting configured entities>
     [java] WLST-WLS-1462290651259: <May 3, 2016 10:51:17 AM CDT> <Warning> <Management> <BEA-141238> <A non-dynamic change has been made which affects the server admin7001. This server must be
 rebooted in order to consume this change.>
     [java] WLST-WLS-1462290651259: <May 3, 2016 10:51:17 AM CDT> <Warning> <Management> <BEA-141239> <The non-dynamic attribute FileName on weblogic.management.configuration.LogMBeanImpl@74f7f
cc0([app7001]/Servers[admin7001]/Log[admin7001]) has been changed. This may require redeploying or rebooting configured entities>
     [java] WLST-WLS-1462290651259: <May 3, 2016 10:51:17 AM CDT> <Warning> <Management> <BEA-141238> <A non-dynamic change has been made which affects the server admin7001. This server must be
 rebooted in order to consume this change.>
     [java] WLST-WLS-1462290651259: <May 3, 2016 10:51:17 AM CDT> <Warning> <Management> <BEA-141239> <The non-dynamic attribute FileName on weblogic.management.configuration.WebServerLogMBeanI
mpl@243a6de4([app7001]/Servers[admin7001]/WebServer[admin7001]/WebServerLog[admin7001]) has been changed. This may require redeploying or rebooting configured entities>
     [java] WLST-WLS-1462290651259: <May 3, 2016 10:51:17 AM CDT> <Warning> <Management> <BEA-141238> <A non-dynamic change has been made which affects the server admin7001. This server must be
 rebooted in order to consume this change.>
     [java]
     [java] The following non-dynamic attribute(s) have been changed on MBeans
     [java] that require server re-start:
     [java] MBean Changed : com.bea:Name=admin7001,Type=Server
     [java] Attributes changed : InterfaceAddress, ListenAddress
     [java]
     [java] MBean Changed : com.bea:Name=admin7001,Type=Log,Server=admin7001
     [java] Attributes changed : FileName, RotateLogOnStartup, RotationType
     [java]
     [java] MBean Changed : Security:Name=myrealmDefaultAuthenticator
     [java] Attributes changed : ControlFlag
     [java]
     [java] MBean Changed : com.bea:Name=app7001,Type=Domain
     [java] Attributes changed : InternalAppsDeployOnDemandEnabled, ProductionModeEnabled
     [java]
     [java] MBean Changed : com.bea:Name=admin7001,Type=WebServerLog,Server=admin7001,WebServer=admin7001
     [java] Attributes changed : FileName, RotateLogOnStartup, RotationType
     [java]
     [java] MBean Changed : com.bea:Name=app7001,Type=SecurityConfiguration
     [java] Attributes changed : AnonymousAdminLookupEnabled
     [java]
     [java] MBean Changed : com.bea:Name=app7001,Type=Log
     [java] Attributes changed : FileName, RotateLogOnStartup, RotationType
     [java]
     [java] Activation completed
     [java]   Creating Libraryjstl
     [java] Deploying application from C:\bea1034\wlserver1034\server\..\common\deployable-libraries\jstl-1.2.war to targets admin7001 (upload=false) ...
     [java] <May 3, 2016 10:51:19 AM CDT> <Info> <J2EE Deployment SPI> <BEA-260121> <Initiating deploy operation for application, jstl [archive: C:\bea1034\wlserver1034\server\..\common\deploya
ble-libraries\jstl-1.2.war], to admin7001 .>
     [java] .Completed the deployment of Application with status completed
     [java] Current Status of your Deployment:
     [java] Deployment command type: deploy
     [java] Deployment State       : completed
     [java] Deployment Message     : no message
     [java]   Creating Applicationapp
     [java] Deploying application from C:\snapshotviews\e872st_DeviA_app_ant2maven_view1\app_vob\app\app\app-ear\target\app.ear to targets admin7001 (upload=false) ...
     [java] <May 3, 2016 10:51:22 AM CDT> <Info> <J2EE Deployment SPI> <BEA-260121> <Initiating deploy operation for application, app [archive: C:\snapshotviews\e872st_DeviA_app_ant2maven_v
iew1\app_vob\app\app\app-ear\target\app.ear], to admin7001 .>
     [java] ...Completed the deployment of Application with status completed
     [java] Current Status of your Deployment:
     [java] Deployment command type: deploy
     [java] Deployment State       : completed
     [java] Deployment Message     : no message
     [java] Shutting down the server admin7001 with force=true while connected to admin7001 ...
     [java] WLST-WLS-1462290651259: <May 3, 2016 10:51:32 AM CDT> <Alert> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000396> <Server shutdown has been requested by wlsboot>
     [java] WLST-WLS-1462290651259: <May 3, 2016 10:51:32 AM CDT> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to FORCE_SUSPENDING>
     [java] WLST-WLS-1462290651259: <May 3, 2016 10:51:32 AM CDT> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to ADMIN>
     [java] WLST-WLS-1462290651259: <May 3, 2016 10:51:32 AM CDT> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to FORCE_SHUTTING_DOWN>
     [java] WLST-WLS-1462290651259: <May 3, 2016 10:51:32 AM CDT> <Notice> <Server> <BEA-002607> <Channel "Default" listening on 127.0.0.1:7001 was shutdown.>
     [java] WLST-WLS-1462290651259: Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
     [java] WLST-WLS-1462290651259: Stopped draining WLST-WLS-1462290651259
     [java] WLST-WLS-1462290651259: Stopped draining WLST-WLS-1462290651259
     [java] WLST lost connection to the WebLogic Server that you were
     [java] connected to, this may happen if the server was shutdown or
     [java] partitioned. You will have to re-connect to the server once the
     [java] server is available.
     [java] Disconnected from weblogic server: admin7001
     [java] Disconnected from weblogic server:
     [java]
     [java]
     [java] Exiting WebLogic Scripting Tool.
     [java]
     [java] Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
     [java] <May 3, 2016 10:51:47 AM CDT> <Warning> <JNDI> <BEA-050001> <WLContext.close() was called in a different thread than the one in which it was created.>
   [delete] Deleting directory C:\snapshotviews\e872st_DeviA_app_ant2maven_view1\app_vob\app\app\app-ear\target\deploy\app7001\servers\admin7001\data\store\default
     [java] Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 9810
     [java] <May 3, 2016 10:51:48 AM CDT> <Info> <Security> <BEA-090905> <Disabling CryptoJ JCE Provider self-integrity check for better startup performance. To enable this check, specify -Dweb
logic.security.allowCryptoJDefaultJCEVerification=true>
     [java] <May 3, 2016 10:51:48 AM CDT> <Info> <Security> <BEA-090906> <Changing the default Random Number Generator in RSA CryptoJ from ECDRBG to FIPS186PRNG. To disable this change, specify
 -Dweblogic.security.allowCryptoJDefaultPRNG=true>
     [java] <May 3, 2016 10:51:48 AM CDT> <Info> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000377> <Starting WebLogic Server with Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM Version 24.51-b03 from Oracle Corporation>
     [java] <May 3, 2016 10:51:49 AM CDT> <Info> <Management> <BEA-141107> <Version: WebLogic Server 10.3.4.0  Fri Dec 17 20:47:33 PST 2010 1384255 >
     [java] <May 3, 2016 10:51:49 AM CDT> <Warning> <Management> <BEA-141275> <Development mode has specified at the command line by setting the weblogic.ProductionModeEnabled system property t
o false. This system property overrides the production mode setting contained in config.xml. However, the console and WLST show the attribute values and defaults that correspond to the producti
on mode specified in config.xml.>
     [java] <May 3, 2016 10:51:50 AM CDT> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to STARTING>
     [java] <May 3, 2016 10:51:50 AM CDT> <Info> <WorkManager> <BEA-002900> <Initializing self-tuning thread pool>
     [java] <May 3, 2016 10:51:50 AM CDT> <Notice> <Log Management> <BEA-170019> <The server log file C:\snapshotviews\e872st_DeviA_app_ant2maven_view1\app_vob\app\app\app-ear\target\
deploy\logs\app7001\admin7001\weblogic.log is opened. All server side log events will be written to this file.>
     [java] <May 3, 2016 10:51:50 AM CDT> <Error> <Socket> <BEA-000438> <Unable to load performance pack. Using Java I/O instead. Please ensure that wlntio.dll is in: 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk
1.7.0_51\jre\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\RationalSDLC\common;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\RationalS
DLC\common;C:\oracle\product\client\11gR4\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Business Objects\Common\3.5\bin\NOTES\;C:\Program Files (x86)\CURL;C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\Wbem;
C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Program Files (x86)\AdminStudio\10.0\Common;C:\CYGWIN\BIN;C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\RationalSDLC\ClearCase\bin;C:
\Program Files (x86)\IBM\gsk8\lib;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\gsk8\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\RationalSDLC\ClearCase\RemoteClient\cteapis;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\RationalSDLC\common;C:\WI
NDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\;C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Progra
m Files\TortoiseGit\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\gsk8\lib;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\gsk8\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\RationalSDLC\ClearCase\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\RationalSDLC\Cle
arCase\RemoteClient\cteapis;C:\snapshotviews\maven\apache-maven-3.3.9\bin;c:\windows\system32\wbem;;.'
     [java] >
     [java] <May 3, 2016 10:51:51 AM CDT> <Notice> <Security> <BEA-090082> <Security initializing using security realm myrealm.>
     [java] <May 3, 2016 10:51:51 AM CDT> <Warning> <Store> <BEA-280101> <The persistent file store "_WLS_admin7001" is forced to use buffered I/O and so may have significantly degraded perform
ance. Either the OS/hardware environment does not support the chosen write policy or the native wlfileio library is missing. See store open log messages for the requested and final write polici
es. See the documentation on store synchronous write policy configuration for advice.>
     [java] <May 3, 2016 10:51:51 AM CDT> <Warning> <Management> <BEA-141277> <The JMX MBean PlatformMBeanServerUsed attribute is true, but the Platform MBeanServer was created without the hook
s for the WLS security infrastructure. The Platform MBeanServer will NOT be used and Platform MBeans will NOT be available via the WLS Runtime or Domain Runtime MBeanServers. This can occur if
you have defined Platform MBeanServer system properties or JVM options (-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote or JRockit -XManagement).
     [java]  To allow the Platform MBeanServer to be used, you must either remove the system properties/JVM options or start WLS with the following system property:
     [java]  -Djavax.management.builder.initial=weblogic.management.jmx.mbeanserver.WLSMBeanServerBuilder
     [java]  If you want to eliminate this log error and do not need Platform MBeans to be available via WLS, then set the PlatformMBeanUsed attribute in the JMXMBean to false.>
     [java] <May 3, 2016 10:51:52 AM CDT> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to STANDBY>
     [java] <May 3, 2016 10:51:52 AM CDT> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to STARTING>
     [java] <May 3, 2016 10:51:58 AM CDT> <Warning> <HTTP> <BEA-101162> <User defined listener org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener failed: java.lang.NullPointerException.
     [java] java.lang.NullPointerException
     [java]     at org.springframework.core.SerializableTypeWrapper$TypeProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(SerializableTypeWrapper.java:239)
     [java]     at org.springframework.core.$Proxy54.hashCode(Unknown Source)
     [java]     at org.springframework.util.ObjectUtils.nullSafeHashCode(ObjectUtils.java:273)
     [java]     at org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.hashCode(ResolvableType.java:811)
     [java]     at org.springframework.util.ConcurrentReferenceHashMap.getHash(ConcurrentReferenceHashMap.java:214)
     [java]     Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
     [java] >
     [java] <May 3, 2016 10:51:58 AM CDT> <Error> <Deployer> <BEA-149231> <Unable to set the activation state to true for the application 'app'.
     [java] weblogic.application.ModuleException:
     [java]     at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1510)
     [java]     at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:482)
     [java]     at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:425)
     [java]     at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
     [java]     at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119)
     [java]     Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
     [java] Caused By: java.lang.NullPointerException
     [java]     at org.springframework.core.SerializableTypeWrapper$TypeProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(SerializableTypeWrapper.java:239)
     [java]     at org.springframework.core.$Proxy54.hashCode(Unknown Source)
     [java]     at org.springframework.util.ObjectUtils.nullSafeHashCode(ObjectUtils.java:273)
     [java]     at org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.hashCode(ResolvableType.java:811)
     [java]     at org.springframework.util.ConcurrentReferenceHashMap.getHash(ConcurrentReferenceHashMap.java:214)
     [java]     Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
     [java] >
     [java] <May 3, 2016 10:51:58 AM CDT> <Notice> <Log Management> <BEA-170027> <The Server has established connection with the Domain level Diagnostic Service successfully.>
     [java] <May 3, 2016 10:51:59 AM CDT> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to ADMIN>
     [java] <May 3, 2016 10:51:59 AM CDT> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to RESUMING>
     [java] <May 3, 2016 10:51:59 AM CDT> <Notice> <Server> <BEA-002613> <Channel "Default" is now listening on 10.32.120.50:7001 for protocols iiop, t3, ldap, snmp, http.>
     [java] <May 3, 2016 10:51:59 AM CDT> <Notice> <Server> <BEA-002613> <Channel "Default[1]" is now listening on 127.0.0.1:7001 for protocols iiop, t3, ldap, snmp, http.>
     [java] <May 3, 2016 10:51:59 AM CDT> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000331> <Started WebLogic Admin Server "admin7001" for domain "app7001" running in Development Mode>
     [java] <May 3, 2016 10:51:59 AM CDT> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to RUNNING>
     [java] <May 3, 2016 10:51:59 AM CDT> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000360> <Server started in RUNNING mode>
```

Weblogic server started in RUNNING mode but the above error occured,
Is it because of the permission issue with a jdbc config file for one of the data sources ??
Unable to set the activation state to true for the application. weblogic.application.ModuleException  and      Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace Caused By: java.lang.NullPointerException

Thanks!

Comment: Have a look here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25533211/spring-mvc-onto-tomcat-8-using-maven-nullpointerexception-with-serializabletype